# Running queries in parallel in Doobie

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, doobie

Is it possible to run multiple queries in parallel, using Doobie?

I have the following (pseudo)queries:

```
def prepareForQuery(input: String): ConnectionIO[Unit] = ???
val gettAllResults: ConnectionIO[List[(String, BigDecimal)]] = ???
def program(input : String) : ConnectionIO[List[(String, BigDecimal)]] = for{
    _ <- prepareForQuery(input)
    r <- gettAllResults
  } yield r
```

What I tried is the following:

```
import doobie._
import doobie.implicits._
import cats.implicits._
val xa = Transactor.fromDataSource[IO](myDataSource)
val result = (program(i1),program(i2)).parMapN{case (a,b) => a ++ b}
val rs = result.transact(xa).unsafeRunSync
```

However, no NonEmptyParallel instance is found for `ConnectionIO`.

> Error:(107, 54) could not find implicit value for parameter p:
>   cats.NonEmptyParallel[doobie.ConnectionIO,F]   val result =
>   (program(i1),program(i2)).parMapN{case (a ,b) => a ++ b}

Am I missing something obvious or trying something that cannot be done?
Thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472904/doobie-and-db-access-composition-within-1-transaction

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Probably stating the obvious, but if you don't need to run both queries in the same transaction, you can `transact` them first and `parMapN` the resulting `IO`s.

Comment: Perhaps this answer can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601408/how-to-execute-list-of-string-sql-statements-against-a-postgresql-db-in-scala-us

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot run queries in the `ConnectionIO` monad in parallel. But as soon as you turn them into your actual runtime monad (as long as it has a Parallel instance), you can.

For example, with the cats-effect IO runtime monad:

```
def prepareForQuery(input: String): ConnectionIO[Unit] = ???
val gettAllResults: ConnectionIO[List[(String, BigDecimal)]] = ???
def program(input : String) : ConnectionIO[List[(String, BigDecimal)]] = for{
    _ <- prepareForQuery(input)
    r <- gettAllResults
  } yield r
```

Turn your `ConnectionIO` into an `IO`

```
val program1IO: IO[List[(String, BigDecimal)]]] = program(i1).transact(xa)
val program2IO: IO[List[(String, BigDecimal)]]] = program(i2).transact(xa)
```

You now have a monad which can do things in parallel.

```
val result: IO[List[(String, BigDecimal)]]] = 
    (program1IO, program2IO).parMapN{case (a,b) => a ++ b}
```

---

To understand why `ConnectionIO` doesn't allow you to do things in parallel, I'll just quote tpolecat:

> You can't run ConnectionIO in parallel. It's a language describing the use of a connection which is a linear sequence of operations.

> Using parMapN in IO, yes, you can run two things at the same time because they're running on different connections.

> There is no parMapN with ConnectionIO because it does not (and cannot) have a Parallel instance.