# How to execute list of string SQL statements against a PostgreSQL db in Scala using doobie?

Tags: scala, doobie

I am porting the following 10 lines of Python code to Scala:

```
import psycopg2

def execute(user, password, database, host, port, *queries):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user=user, password=password, host=host, port=port, database=database)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for sql in queries:
        print(sql)
        cursor.execute(sql)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

I have the following equivalent Scala code:

```
def execute(user: String, password: String, database: String, host: String, port: Int, queries: String*): Unit = {
  ???
}
```

I want to execute (and print) bunch of SQL statements in a *single transaction* against the database (assume it to be Postgres) and be done.

How do I do that using [doobie](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie)?

Note:

1. I cannot change the interface to my `execute()` (including I cannot add type or implicit params). It *must* take in String user, password etc. and a vararg of `queries: String*` and thus keep the interface same as the Python one.
2. Please also mention all imports needed

Comment: are these queries updates, selects or inserts?

Comment: Mostly, create tables, create views, refresh, copy statements to load data, renames etc.

Comment: I checked with doobie - but I did not find a possibility - so are you only interested in solution with doobie - or in scala in general?

Comment: doobie only unfortunately as that's the library we use everywhere in our codebase. I am quite surprised its not possible to execute a `Seq[String]` in one of the most popular ORM library in Scala!

Comment: Is it an ORM library?

Comment: Sorry, a database library to execute queries, not ORM. Even more the reason that it does not support executing arbitrary list of strings as @pme said is kind of outrageous!

Comment: Why is it outrageous?

Comment: A popular database library for a popular language cannot execute a list of arbitrary SQL statements when it is 7 lines in Python :) But maybe @pme is wrong and there is way ... just not documented or obvious..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run multiple queries in one transaction in doobie using for-comprehension, for example:

```
val query = for {
   _  <- sql"insert into person (name, age) values ($name, $age)".update.run
   id <- sql"select lastval()".query[Long].unique
} yield p
```

But this solution won't work in your case, because you've got a dynamic list of queries. Fortunately, we can use [traverse](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/applicative.html#traverse) from cats:

```
import cats.effect.ContextShift
import doobie._
import doobie.implicits._
import cats.effect._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import cats.implicits._
import cats._
import cats.data._

def execute(user: String, password: String, database: String, host: String, port: Int, queries: String*): Unit = {

     //you can use other executor if you want
     //it would be better to pass context shift as implicit argument to method
    implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global) 

    //let's create transactor  
    val xa = Transactor.fromDriverManager[IO](
      "org.postgresql.Driver",
       s"jdbc:postgresql://$host:$port/$database", //remember to change url or make it dynamic, if you run it agains another database
       user,
       password
    )

    val batch = queries
        .toList //we need to change String* to list, since String* doesn't have necessary typeclass for Aplicative
        .traverse(query => Update0(query, None).run) //we lift strings to Query0 and then run them, then we change List[ConnectionIO[Int]] to ConnectionIO[List[Int]]
        //above can be done in two steps using map and sequence

    batch  //now we've got single ConnectionIO which will run in one transaction
      .transact(xa) //let's make it IO[Int]
      .unsafeRunSync() //we need to block since your method returns Unit

  }
```

Probably your IDE will show you this code is invalid, but it's correct. IDEs just can't handle Scala magic.

You might also consider using `unsafeRunTimed` instead of `unsafeRunSync` to add the time limit.

Also, remember to add [postgresql driver for jdbc](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql) and [cats](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.typelevel/cats-core) to your `build.sbt`. Doobie uses cats under the hood, but I think explicit dependency might be necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Try solving it for just one query in a transaction and seeing what that function signature looks like.

Then look at how to get from there to your final destination.