# Doobie - lifting arbitrary effect into ConnectionIO

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect, doobie

I'm trying to send an email in the same transaction as inserting user into a database with Doobie.
I know that I can lift `IO` into `ConnectionIO` by using `Async[ConnectionIO].liftIO(catsIO)` where `catsIO: IO[String]`
But in my code I don't operate on `IO`, I use `F` with constraints, for example `F[_]: Async`
So then I can replace `F` with my own monad for testing.

Is it possible to somehow lift an `F[String]` into `ConnectionIO[String]` without using `IO` type directly?

Here is an answer I found for IO type: [Doobie and DB access composition within 1 transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472904/doobie-and-db-access-composition-within-1-transaction)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cats has something called FunctionK which is a natural transformation.

I did this:

At the top of the world, where everything is built, you will need this

```
val liftToConnIO: FunctionK[IO, ConnectionIO] = LiftIO.liftK[ConnectionIO]
```

In the class needing to transform from F[String] to G[String] (F will be IO, G will be ConnectionIO when you construct everything) you can pass `liftToConnIO` and use it to transform F[A]to G[A] where needed.

The class that doesn't wants to abstract over IO and ConnectionIO can be passed the FunctionK to do the lifting:

```
class Stuff[F[_], G[_]](emailer: Emailer[F], store: Store[G], liftToG: FunctionK[F, G]) {

  def sendEmail: G[Unit] =
    for {
      _ <- doDatabaseThingsReturnStuffInG
      _ <- liftToG(emailer.sendEmail)
      _ <- doMoreDatabaseThingsReturnStuffInG
     } yield ()

}
```

(You might need context bounds (Sync?) on F and G)

Comment: Note that starting at Doobie 1.0.0, things have changed. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71212284/doobie-lifting-arbitrary-effect-into-connectionio-ce3

Answer (score 4):

A variation on Channing's answer,

```scala
class Stuff[F[_] : Effect, G[_] : LiftIO](emailer: Emailer[F], store: Store[G]) {

  def sendEmail: G[Unit] =
    for {
      _ <- doDatabaseThingsReturnStuffInG
      _ <- emailer.sendEmail.toIO.to[G]
      _ <- doMoreDatabaseThingsReturnStuffInG
     } yield ()
}
```

`Effect[F]` supports taking an `F[A]` to an `IO[A]` via `toIO`, and `LiftIO[G]` supports taking an `IO[A]` to a `G[A]` via `to[G]`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can easily instantiate your `F[String]` into `ConnectionIO[String]`.
Given a function like:

```
def foo[F[_]: Async]: F[String] = ...
```

To instantiate in to `ConnectionIO` you can simply do this:

```
def fooCIO: ConnectionIO[String] = foo[ConnectionIO]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Doobie 1.x (with cats-effect 3), the `LiftIO` instance for `ConnectionIO` no longer exists ([why](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie/pull/1280#discussion_r604959872))

Instead you want to use `WeakAsync.liftK` as mentioned in [Doobie - lifting arbitrary effect into ConnectionIO CE3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71212284/doobie-lifting-arbitrary-effect-into-connectionio-ce3)